# canvas vs webgl client library to draw map vector tiles

Tags: openstreetmap, software-recommendations, vector-tiles

For a map application using `pbf` vector tiles, should I go with [Tangrams](https://github.com/tangrams/tangram) which uses webgl to draw the tiles or some other library (e.g. [Hoverboard](https://github.com/devTristan/hoverboard))?

Tangrams looks very promising since it abstracts out the tile styling to a `.yaml` file, but it won't work on clients without webgl support, and the ones on which it will, I'm afraid it'll consume more resources than a library using canvas.

So on a related note, which would be better - using canvas or webgl to render a map?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Pixi.js](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js) that renders on WebGL but fallback on Canvas in case WebGL is not available.